# Flowtype errors in a simple constructor function

Tags: javascript, constructor, flowtype

Why does flowtype report the following error and how would this need to be documented to work as expected?

```
index.js:7
  4: console.log(MY_OBJECT.getName());
                           ^^^^^^^ property `getName`. Property not found in
  4: console.log(MY_OBJECT.getName());
                 ^^^^^^^^^ new object
```

index.js

```
// @flow
import {MyObject} from './object';
const MY_OBJECT = new MyObject('name');
console.log(MY_OBJECT.getName());
```

object.js:

```
// @flow
export function MyObject(name: string) {
    this._name = name;
    this.getName = function (): string {return this._name;};
    this.setName = function (name: string) {this._name = name;};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out, that it actually does work when explicitly returning this:

```
// @flow
export function MyObject(name: string) {
    this._name = name;
    this.getName = function (): string {return this._name;};
    this.setName = function (name: string) {this._name = name;};
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Flow doesn't like this style. When you use it in the same module, it will work, but when you import it from another file, it won't.

It is recommended to use the [ES2015 class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) instead:

```
// @flow
export class MyObject {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string){
        this.name = name;
    }

    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    setName(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If you don't like this, you can use prototypes, that [has limited support](https://flowtype.org/docs/quick-reference.html#sugar-free-classes):

```
// @flow
export function MyObject(name: string) {
  this._name = name;        
}

MyObject.prototype.getName = function (): string {return this._name;};
MyObject.prototype.setName = function (name: string) {this._name = name;};
```